# Sorting users by points (using merit gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

What's the best way to order a users list by their points generated by the merit gem? I'm having difficulty doing so because merit probably doesn't save it's data in the db.

So far, I'm caching merit points in the users table, I was just wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution I have found is https://github.com/tute/merit/wiki/How-to-show-a-points-leaderboard

Answer (score 3):

In your User model, you can define the default scope:

```
        scope :ordered, ->{ joins('LEFT JOIN merit_scores ON ' \
                                   merit_scores.sash_id = "users".sash_id ' \
                                  'LEFT JOIN merit_score_points ON merit_score_points.score_id = merit_scores.id')
                           .group('"users".id')
                           .order('COALESCE(SUM(num_points), 0) DESC') }
```

Comment: Made some changes. What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

This will exclude users with no points

```
User.joins('RIGHT JOIN merit_scores ON merit_scores.sash_id = users.sash_id RIGHT JOIN merit_score_points ON merit_score_points.score_id = merit_scores.id')
    .group('users.id', 'merit_scores.sash_id')
    .order('SUM(num_points) DESC').limit(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you've been down-voted by someone because your question is very ambiguous. SO is for programming-specific questions (you need to include code)

---

**Order**

In terms of an answer, it will be to use the [`.order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) ActiveRecord function:

```
User.merits.order(:vote)
```

As you've not provided much code, any further help I try to provide would just be guesswork - no help to anyone. Maybe you could update your answer with some more details?

Comment: updated question. The key thing i missed is that it's about the `merit` gem (although I did tag merit-gem)